# Display Second Result of Duplicate Lines in Text File

Tags: string, unix, awk, grep, uniq

I am trying to display the second result of duplicate lines in a text file.

**Data:**
`60 60 61 64 63 78 78`

**Duplicate Lines:**
`60 60 78 78`

**Attempted Code:**
`echo "60 60 61 64 63 78 78" | sed 's/ /\n/g' | uniq -D | tail -1`

**Current Result:**
`78`

**Expected Result:**
`60 78`

Comment: Then why did you use `| tail -1`?

Comment: `echo "60 60 61 64 63 78 78" | xargs -n1 | sort | uniq -d | xargs`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try this `gnu awk` solution:

```sh
s='60 60 61 64 63 78 78'
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '++fq[$0] == 2' <<< "$s"

60
78
```

To avoid getting line breaks after each line:

```sh
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '++fq[$0] == 2 {printf "%s", $0 RT}' <<< "$s"

60 78
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you could have multiple lines in your Input_file then you could try following.

```
awk '
{
  delete value
  num=split($0,arr," ")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    value[arr[i]]++
  }
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    if(value[arr[i]]>1){
      print arr[i]
      delete value[arr[i]]
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                          ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  delete value                 ##Deleting value array here.
  num=split($0,arr," ")        ##Splitting current line to array arr here.
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){         ##Traversing through all fields here.
    value[arr[i]]++            ##Creating value array with value of arr array.
  }
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){         ##Traversing through all fields here.
    if(value[arr[i]]>1){       ##Checking condition if value array value is coming more than 1 times then do following.
      print arr[i]             ##printing array value here(which is value which comes more than 1 time).
      delete value[arr[i]]     ##Deleting value array value to avoid duplicate printing here.
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file                  ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you do not want to then do not use `tail -1`.  And instead of printing all, print duplicates once per duplicate.

```
echo "60 60 61 64 63 78 78" | sed 's/ /\n/g' | sort | uniq -d
```

Note - if the input is not sorted (or duplicate lines are not adjacent), you need to sort it first.

Comment: I am looking for the *second* result of *all* duplicate lines, not just the last lines.

Comment: The comment makes no sense. `second result of all duplicate lines,` if all lines are the same (are duplicates) then the order does not matter. It's irrelevant if the line is second or first or third or in any order, because all the duplicate lines contents are the same. I do not understand why the "second result" of a duplicate group should be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ printf '%s\n' 60 60 61 64 63 78 78 | uniq -d
60
78
```

The above is assuming a hard-coded list of numbers works for you since, per the example in your question, you thought `echo "60 60 61 64 63 78 78" | sed 's/ /\n/g' | uniq -D | tail -1` would work for you. If you need to store them in a variable first then make it an array variable:

```
$ vals=(60 60 60 61 64 63 78 78)
$ printf '%s\n' "${vals[@]}" | uniq -d
60
78
```